# Why does $\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 r^2 $cos$\theta\ dr d \theta \neq 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 r^2 $cos$\theta\ dr d \theta $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Apparently this inequality:

$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 r^2 \cos \theta\  dr d \theta \neq 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 r^2 \cos \theta\  dr d \theta $$

Is true. But why? I sketched out the regions of integration and the right hand side is the top half of the unit circle, and the left hand side is simply half of that hemisphere. So multiplying it by two gives the same region, and since the integrands are the same shouldn't these integrals be equal?

Comment: I guess you sketch with a modulus of $\cos$? It is the same if you change the boundary to $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ or take the modulus of $\cos$.

Comment: This inequality can be an equality when you replace $\cos\theta$ by $|\cos\theta|$ on the left hand side. The $r$ integration doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $\cos \theta $ is positive in the first quadrant but changes sign in the second quadrant so the function values are not symmetrical.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$0=\int_0^\pi \cos\theta\ d\theta\neq2\int_0^{\pi\over2} \cos\theta\ d\theta=2$$

Answer (score 1):

because $r$ and $\theta$ are separable, this is the same as saying:
$$\int_0^\pi\cos(\theta) d\theta\ne2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
and since:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\cos(\theta)d\theta=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
$$\int_0^\pi\cos(\theta)d\theta=0$$
whilst:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)d\theta\ne0$$